# Continuously differentiable vs Continuous derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

I am wondering whether two characteristics of a function are identical or not? that is:

1- A function has derivative over an open interval

2- The derivative of a function exists and is continuous over an open interval ($C^1$ functions)

If not, please include any example that comes to your mind in your answer that works for a set of greater than measure-zero set, thanks

Comment: To me, continuously differentiable means differentiable with continuous derivative.

Comment: ok, I removed the "continuously differentiable function" tag on first charachtersitic to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

Let define the following map: $$f:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{R} & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}\\x & \mapsto & \left\{\begin{array}{cc}\displaystyle x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&\textrm{ if }x\neq 0\\0 &\textrm{ if }x=0\end{array}\right.\end{array}\right..$$
$f$ is differentiable and is derivatives is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: You need a little bit more decay at zero than that to have a derivative at zero.

Comment: Fixed, you're right indeed!

Comment: Could you give an example that shows that the functions is not differentiable at a set that has non-zero measure? I mean it is deferntiable on a open continous interval but the derivative is not continuous on any open interval and has discontinuity on more than a set of measure zero

Comment: What a weird way to write a function.

Comment: Yes, I think it is not possible and actually the discontinuity can only be on a set of measure zero and no more

Comment: I won't be so sure, it might exists pathologic counterexamples! Howeover, I don't have one right now.

Comment: @SaraWinslet: Playing on words, the function $f$ I have defined would do the job for the Dirac's measure at the origin. More seriously, your question for the Lebesgue's measure is pretty interesting!

Comment: @SaraWinslet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function The key is that there exists a nowhere dense set of positive measure, which is a very surprising fact. But once you know that the rest of the construction is in some sense "obvious" (not in the sense that it is easy, but in the sense that you basically "follow your nose" and get the right answer).

Comment: @Sara if you search this site you'll find examples of derivatives of everywhere differentiable functions that are discontinuous on a set of positive measure.

Comment: Wow, what an intelligent design of the function, thx